# How to enable Remote Desktop User - Post Deployment/ Post Build for Azure Services

Tags: azure, rdp, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

Would like to know if there is a way to enable RDP post Deployment. Post Build of a Cloud Service?

Options are available before packaging to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution for this!

**Set-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension**

You need the ServiceName to be passed to the snippet below.

```
        if(($UserName) -and ($Password))
        {
            $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $Password -AsPlainText -Force
            $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName, $SecurePass

            # Check if RDP is enabled for the Service
            $isRDPEnaled = Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension -ServiceName $ServiceName
            if(!$isRDPEnaled)
            {
                # Enable RDP with the new user
                Set-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension -ServiceName $ServiceName -Credential $Credential
            }
            else
            {
                if($isRDPEnaled.UserName -ne $UserName)
                {
                    # Remove RDP for the existing user
                    Remove-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension -ServiceName $ServiceName
                    # Enable RDP with the new user
                    Set-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension -ServiceName $ServiceName -Credential $Credential
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose ""
                    Write-Verbose " Remote Login enabled for the Service "
                }
            }
        }
```